# django/python count number of row inserted in specific month

Tags: python, django, datetime, count

Purchase_History model

```
class Purchase_History(models.Model):
   barcode = models.BigIntegerField()
   email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   bill_no = models.IntegerField()
   longitude = models.CharField(max_length=500)
   latitude = models.CharField(max_length=500)
   timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, auto_now = False)
```

i want to count number of rows from specific month 
i tried something like

```
m=Purchase_History.objects.filter(timestamp="month").count()
```

and

```
m=Purchase_History.objects.filter(timestamp=["2017-01-01", "2017-01-31"]).count()
```

its good practice to use timestamp field, please help me, if you have any solution to it.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `__range` filter:

```
Purchase_History.objects.filter(timestamp__range=["2017-01-01", "2017-01-31"]).count()
```